# kendo grid datasource not update, when push new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I got an array object that can select buyer, if select i will push their data to `selectedBuyers` , if unselect will filter out from `selectedBuyers`. So I would like to update the kendo grid while I push / filter array.

What I have test is when i push new object to array , i call `$("#my-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();` the grid have update, this work fine. However when i filter out some object from array, and call `$("#my-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();` or `$("#my-grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();` or both , the grid is still showing old data.

```
var selectedBuyers = [{
    "Name":"A",
    "Price":"",
    "Total":""
},{
    "Name":"B",
    "Price":"",
    "Total":""
}];

$("#my-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: selectedBuyers,
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    Price: { type: "string" },
                    Total: { type: "string" },
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    },
    pageable: {
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 15, 20],
    },
    scrollable: true,
    dataBound: onbuyerDataBound,
    columns: [ {
        field: "Name",
        title: "Name",
        width: 100
    },
    {
        field: "Price",
        title: "Price",
        width: 100
        },
    {
        field: "Total",
        title: "Total",
        width: 110,
    }]
});
```

Comment: `when i filter out some object from array` - what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

You cant just filter out data that you don't want. You need to `remove` it from `dataSource`.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe" },
    { id: 2, name: "John Doe" }
  ],
  schema: {
    model: { id: "id" }
  }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource
})

$("#remove").kendoButton({
  click: function() {
    var dataItem = dataSource.at(0);
    dataSource.remove(dataItem);
  }
});
```

Working example: [Remove grid item](https://dojo.telerik.com/OGEBOCEf)